# Postfix reject emails due to reverse DNS lookup failure when manual lookup works fine

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, smtp

I have bumped into the following in my `mail.log` file:

```
May 20 21:50:46 degas postfix/smtpd[1596]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[109.170.250.177]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [109.170.250.177]; from=<***> to=<***> proto=ESMTP helo=<jamnet.jamrec.jamjobs.co.uk>
```

In postfix configuration the `reject_unknown_client_hostname` is set on `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`

What I find slightly baffling is that `dig -x 109.170.250.177` returns a valid answer:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;177.250.170.109.in-addr.arpa.  IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
177.250.170.109.in-addr.arpa. 67434 IN  PTR     mail.jamjobs.co.uk.
```

According to the postfix documentation this is what this config option does

> Reject the request when 1) the client
>   IP address->name mapping fails, 2) the
>   name->address mapping fails, or 3) the
>   name->address mapping does not match
>   the client IP address.

In this case, condition 1) is met, but condition 3) seems to cause the failure.

I could change to `reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname` to fix the problem.

Would you suggest that my current setting is too "strong" or too "restrictive"? Should I normally expect the announced hostname of the SMTPD client be potentially different from the IP address lookup? Is this configuration helpful protecting from spam. Currently it seems to cause too many false negatives.

Answer (score 4):

You're interpreting the error wrong:

```
% host jamnet.jamrec.jamjobs.co.uk
Host jamnet.jamrec.jamjobs.co.uk not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

That's your problem - the HELO/EHLO identified hostname, not the IP.